# Stress Tensor decomposition into Compression & Tensile forces

Tags: structural-engineering, structural-analysis, finite-element-method, stresses

I'm working on a project that does a finite element simulation of a mesh. I can output the stress tensor at each node, but I'm not so sure how to implement failure criteria.

If my material is brittle, say concrete, what's the best way to identify failure?

My current approach is to compute the von mises stress and compare against the compressive yield strength of the material, however this is completely ignoring the possibility that some portions of the mesh might be under tensile stresses for which the yield strength might be much lower.

Is it possible to resolve the stress tensor into tensile and compressive components?

Thanks!
Clayton

Answer (score 1):

A good starting point is a failure criterion such as Willam-Warnke (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Willam-Warnke_yield_criterion).  Note that the shape of the failure surface is approximately triangular, indicating different strengths under uniaxial compression and tension.

If you don't have data on the biaxial compression of the material, you can play around with the parameters until you get a surface that approximates the material.